# Write the following as an algebraic expression of x; sinh(lnx)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

So I have a questions asking for $sinh(log_ex)$

sinh(x) = $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

So $sinh(log_x)$ = $\frac{e^{lnx}-e^{-lnx}}{2}$

$\frac{e^{lnx}-e^{lnx^{-1}}}{2}$

= $\frac{x - x^{-1}}{2}$

=$\frac{x-1}{2x}$

However the answer is $\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$

Can't seem to find where we went wrong

Comment: $\frac{x - x^{-1}}{2} =\frac{x^2 - 1}{2x}$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{x-x^{-1}}{2} = \frac{x-x^{-1}}{2} \frac{x}{x} = \frac{x^2-1}{2x}$$

Comment: Doesn't $\frac{x^{-1}}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{2x}$? Therefore the answer would be $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$?

Comment: @user88720:  In what way is that different from what I wrote?  $\frac{x^2}{2x} = \frac{x}{2}$...

Answer (score 1):

You were incorrect when saying $\dfrac{x-x^{-1}}{2}=\dfrac{x-1}{2}$.
$$\frac{x-x^{-1}}{2}=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{-1}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x}$$
$$=\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$$
Hope I helped.

Comment: I fixed a minor typo. Cheers.